# R: Is cut the right function to do this?

Tags: r, cut

I'm currently struggling with cut...I don't know if there's another function for this.

I have big table with values and a matrix or vector with thresholds.

Let's say I have a matrix containing the thresholds 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4
I want to find out for a value (i.e. 0.9) in which sector this value falls. Basically it's a "grading" System. A Value <= 0.6 gets a 5, <= 0.8 and > 0.6 gets a 4 etc. So I want to write only this value (5, 4, 3 etc.) into the resulting table.

Ok here's the code I have so far:

```
cut(1.2, breaks=c(0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4), labels(5,4,3,2,1))
```

But this doesn't work yet..with the labels I actually don't know how many I have to insert there since I always get an error that the lenghts of the vectors are different. Without the labels parameter I still don't get it to work correctly. It still outputs all different segments and not only the one the value is in I guess...

Comment: The way you wrote it there is no category for `<=0.6`. `cut(1.2, breaks=c(0,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4), labels=c(5,4,3,2,1))` would be more correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`cut` should be the correct function, but you're doing things wrong.

First, there are typos in your code. `labels = c(...)` would be the correct version.

Second, think about what you're doing: creating intervals. How many? Try `cut` without the `labels` to see:

```
cut(1.2, breaks=c(0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4))
# [1] (1,1.2]
# Levels: (0.6,0.8] (0.8,1] (1,1.2] (1.2,1.4]
```

There are only 4 levels created the way you're doing it, so you only need to provide 4 labels (or redefine your break points).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `findInterval` :

```
breaks <- c(0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4)
val <- c(0.7,1.1,1.35)
findInterval(val, breaks)
## [1] 1 3 4
```

If you want labels for the results, you can use a factor :

```
labels <- factor(5:1)
labels[findInterval(val,breaks)]
##  [1] 5 3 2
##  Levels: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2):

`findInterval` suits good enough in this situation

```
x <- c(0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4)
> findInterval(0.9, x)
[1] 2
```

This means that your value `0.9` is in the second interval, namely, between `0.8` and `1.0`. Take a look at `?findInterval` for further details.

Comment: but `findInterval` uses intervals that are opened on the right hand side, not closed like the OP wants. So you have to work in negative space: `grade <- function(x, breaks) findInterval(-x, rev(-breaks))`.  Or you can subtract a machine-epsilon to one of your vectors.

Comment: You're right @flodel, I hadn't realized about that, thanks for pointing that out ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thx a lot sorry still new to R and the learning curve is indeed very high.

Problem is and was that any value <= 0.6 should get the best grade and any value > 1.4 should get the worst. With findInterval it was always >= so I didn't succeed. But I got it working like this with your help:

```
cut(1.2, breaks=c(0,0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,100),labels=c(6,5,4,3,2,1))
```